# attributeerror module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'videocapture'

Tags: python, opencv, cmake, face-recognition, dlib

My project is a face recognition attendance system. When I run in my pycharm project why does it show me error:

> attributeerror module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'videocapture.*

When you run my code my project is automatically taking attendance and saves to another file.

my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import face_recognition
import os
from datetime import datetime

# from PIL import ImageGrab

path = 'Training_images'
images = []
classNames = []
myList = os.listdir(path)
print(myList)
for cl in myList:
    curImg = cv2.imread(f'{path}/{cl}')
    images.append(curImg)
    classNames.append(os.path.splitext(cl)[0])
print(classNames)


def findEncodings(images):
    encodeList = []


    for img in images:
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        encode = face_recognition.face_encodings(img)[0]
        encodeList.append(encode)
    return encodeList


def markAttendance(name):
    with open('Attendance.csv', 'r+') as f:
        myDataList = f.readlines()


        nameList = []
        for line in myDataList:
            entry = line.split(',')
            nameList.append(entry[0])
            if name not in nameList:
                now = datetime.now()
                dtString = now.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
                f.writelines(f'\n{name},{dtString}')

#### FOR CAPTURING SCREEN RATHER THAN WEBCAM
# def captureScreen(bbox=(300,300,690+300,530+300)):
#     capScr = np.array(ImageGrab.grab(bbox))
#     capScr = cv2.cvtColor(capScr, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
#     return capScr

encodeListKnown = findEncodings(images)
print('Encoding Complete')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
# img = captureScreen()
    imgS = cv2.resize(img, (0, 0), None, 0.25, 0.25)
    imgS = cv2.cvtColor(imgS, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    facesCurFrame = face_recognition.face_locations(imgS)
    encodesCurFrame = face_recognition.face_encodings(imgS, facesCurFrame)

    for encodeFace, faceLoc in zip(encodesCurFrame, facesCurFrame):
        matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(encodeListKnown, encodeFace)
        faceDis = face_recognition.face_distance(encodeListKnown, encodeFace)
# print(faceDis)
        matchIndex = np.argmin(faceDis)

        if matches[matchIndex]:
            name = classNames[matchIndex].upper()
# print(name)
            y1, x2, y2, x1 = faceLoc
            y1, x2, y2, x1 = y1 * 4, x2 * 4, y2 * 4, x1 * 4
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 2)
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y2 - 35), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), cv2.FILLED)
            cv2.putText(img, name, (x1 + 6, y2 - 6), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, (255, 255, 255), 2)
            markAttendance(name)

    cv2.imshow('Webcam', img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of place where it could potentially go wrong.

- Improper installation
- Some file with a name cv2 in the working directory.

If you haven't installed opencv for python, go ahead and install first by running this command on Command prompt(Windows) or terminal(linux)

On linux:

```
pip3 install opencv-python
```

On windows:

```
python -m pip install opencv-python
```

After installing, check if it has insatlled properly by running the below python command

```
import cv2
print(cv2.__file__)
```

This will show where the libraries are pointing to.

Also, make sure that you don't have any file named cv2 in the same working directory, else your python interpreter will load that file instead of your opencv libraries.